# how to change background color and text color of v-select active item

Tags: vuetify.js, v-select

can you please help to change v-select active item text color and background color?. I tried with item-color property changes text and background both.how to change text and background color in different colors?

```
 
    <v-select
     color="#ffa20b"
     background-color="#ffffff"
     v-model="x"
     append-icon="keyboard_arrow_down"
     :items="areaCodeListOptions"
     item-text="state"
     :menu-props="{ bottom: true, offsetY: true }"
     @change="y"
     outlined
     dense
     >
   </v-select>
```